# Trying to send a Hashmap array with web service

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I'm trying to send an array that contains a HashMap`<String,Object>` using a web service in Android, but I'm having an exception that says "can not serialize HashMap", hope you will help me guys. Thanks in advance!
Here is the web service class below:

```
public class AddUser {

String namespace = "the name space";
private String url = "the url";
String SOAP_ACTION;
SoapObject request;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport;

AddUser() {
}


//set envelope
protected void SetEnvelope() {

    try {

        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(url);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Soap Exception---->>>" + e.toString());
    }
}


public String SetFicheUser(String MethodName,Object full_tab)
{

    try {
        SOAP_ACTION = "the soap action";

        //Adding values to request object
        request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);
        PropertyInfo prop = new PropertyInfo();
        prop.setName("user");
        prop.setValue(full_tab);
        prop.setType(Object.class);
        request.addProperty(prop);
        SetEnvelope();


        try {

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
            return "";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return e.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return e.toString();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why cant u prefer Namevaluepair instead of hashmap ??

Comment: The web service i'm using must have a hashmap array as parameter.

Comment: Did objects in map are serializable? They should be. Or convert map to JSON object and send.

Comment: the objects i have in my map, are Strings and integers.

Comment: where HashMap is filled?

Comment: the hashmap is contained in the full_tab object which is filled in another class.